# How to read custom claim value from JWT security token in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, bearer-token

I can't read token claims from Bearer JWT token.

Login is working, the HTTP request comes with a valid JWT token to the backend.
Login returns the token.
Here is my code on server side:

Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(m => {
    //m.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    m.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    m.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(conf => {
        conf.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    conf.SaveToken = true;
    conf.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
       ValidateIssuer = true,
       ValidateAudience = true,
       ValidIssuer = Configuration["JWT-Issuer"],
       ValidAudience = Configuration["JWT-Issuer"],
       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JWT-Key"])),
       ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
};
});
```

When I uncomment this line `//m.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` postman says unauthorized. When it is kept commented, authorization succeeds.

Token is generated here.

GenerateToken Method:

```cs
private object GenerateJwtToken(string Id, string email, ApplicationUser appUser, string appUserRole, string FirstName)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = null;
            claims = new List<Claim> {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email,email),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, appUser.Id),
                new Claim("Role",appUserRole),
                new Claim("UserName",appUser.UserName),
                new Claim("TEMP", FirstName)
                }
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT-Key"]));
            var cred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var expire = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["JWT-Expiry"]));


            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["JWT-Issuer"],
                audience: _configuration["JWT-Issuer"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: expire,
                signingCredentials: cred
                );


            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

        }
```

When JWT Bearer token is passed to the API call decorated with `[Authorize]` and tested with debugger it shows that custom claim **like TEMP** is not present in the `User.Claims` List.

Reading Claims From Token

```cs
  string Email = User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")).Value;
  string FirstName= User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("TEMP")).Value;
```

Here, the email can be read successfully but I can't read the FirstName from the token. In fact `User.Claims` doesn't have the `FirstName` claim (I mean all the custom claims leaving the Registered JWT Default ClaimTypes), it only has the default token parameters which are emailaddress, id, role etc.

What should I do?
should I need to create custom authentication scheme for this purpose?

Comment: Can you post a sample copy of the JWT token?

Answer (score 3):

Internally in AddJwtBearer, there are some remapping done by the Token hander, where claims are renamed, like

```
email -> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress
```

This mapping can be turned of using:

```
// Or set this flag to false
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    ...
    opt.MapInboundClaims = false;
});
```

or setting:

```
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultOutboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```

The actual mapping can be found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs)

However, I am not sure why the TEMP claim is not found. What claims do you actually see in the authenticated User in your controller? Some claims, in some cases, are also ignored.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging JwtBearer Claim Problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: Yes I came to know about renaming the claims.

I tried both options and settings you mentioned but do not worked.

Comment: Can I get token from `Authorization` header of `IHttpContextAccessor` in controllers. Will there be any disadvantage for doing this in each controller?

Comment: You should get the user from the ClaimsPrincipal user object, that is the proper way of doing it and I don't think you will gain anything by doing some custom hack.

Comment: is the IsAuthenticated property set to true in the user object? As are you sure you get a real user out of the token? because you need to establish if the token is accepted and an authenticated user is created as the result

Comment: I tried the second way to read claims from the token and I got succeed. Read token through this line and converted it to json.  `string[] SplitResult = _httpcontext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: Can you post what you see in the User object? is the IsAuthenticated property set to true in the user object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239810/discussion-between-saqlain-jan-and-tore-nestenius).